# How to do you include a class in Symfony2?

Tags: php, class, include, symfony

I have read the Symfony documentation and I am still unsure of how to include a class. I want to include a Google Analytics PHP class into Symfony, but not sure on the following:

1. Where should it go? From the documentation I assume it should be under the vendor directory?
2. How would I then include the class? Ideally I would only like to include it where necessary (ie when I need it).
3. How would I then utilise the class?

Cheers

Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `app/autoload.php` file to configure your autoload mechanism.

If your class doesn't follow PEAR style conventions or PSR-0 standards then you should plainly require it (as is the case with Swiftmailer in the same file)

If your class follows PEAR conventions then you should use `registerPrefixes` method else, if your class follows PSR-0 standard (maybe not the case), you should use the `registerNamespaces` method